# AndroidX suddenly causing build failure for NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

All of a sudden, with no changes to my dependencies, I am now getting the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:2-31:16 to override.
```

I have tried applying the suggestion (along with the relevant namespace XML attribute), but unfortunately this yields a message along the lines of `multiple errors, see logs`, but I don't know where the logs are.

I've read and read into this, and I understand it's a problem with attempting to have AndroidX and the now deprecated support libraries at the same time. However, I have not changed any of my dependencies before this suddenly stopped building - only cleared my platforms to force a full rebuild.

I do not know which plugins are conflicting, and I also understand that [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) should remedy this, except NativeScript seems to not give me the ability to modify `gradle.properties` in any persistent way (that I am aware of), and currently the latest version of NativeScript (which is confusing because [NativeScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript) is `5.4.1`, [TNS core modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-core-modules) is `5.4.2` and the platform added in my `package.json` seems to be `5.4.0`) seems to not utilise `Jetifier` and the latest AndroidX build on NPM seems to be a bit out of date.

So, how can I get my app back up and running now? Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I fixed this by moving my support dependencies into `before-plugins.gradle`, which now looks like this:

```
project.ext {
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.0"
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
  def googlePlayServicesVersion = project.googlePlayServicesVersion
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  def supportVer = "28.0.0"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVer"
  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVer"
  compile "com.android.support:design:$supportVer"
}
```

And for good measure, here's my `app.gradle`:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Fix for: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
    // (see: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}

def settingsGradlePath

if(project.hasProperty("appResourcesPath")){
    settingsGradlePath = "$project.appResourcesPath/Android/settings.gradle";
} else {
    settingsGradlePath = "$rootDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/settings.gradle";
}

def settingsGradleFile = new File(settingsGradlePath);

if(settingsGradleFile.exists())
{
    apply from: settingsGradleFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the following dependencies did it for me.

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'

    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'){

    force = true

  }

  implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'){

    force = true

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by taking a look to ./gradlew app:dependencies and i fixed  any package that appeared to be using an updated dependency that uses androidx to a previous version.

[image]

So you can see here that tagmanager was resolving as 17 because the dependency uses '+', so instead i fixed this one to 16.0.8

```
implementation (project(':react-native-device-info')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
}

implementation (project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-analytics'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl'
}
implementation (project(':react-native-admob')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0') {
    force = true
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0') {
    force = true
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8') {
    force = true
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:16.0.8') {
    force = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only updated GooglePlayservices to 15.0.0 and added this to the AndroidManifest inside `<application>`.

```
 <application>
     ...
              <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" 
               android:required="false"/>
     ...            

    <application/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got same error, check libraries version, for me, Firebase was the problem.

`before-plugins.gradle`

```java
project.ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    googleFirebaseServicesVersion = "18.0.0"
}

dependencies {

    def googlePlayServicesVersion = project.googlePlayServicesVersion
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googleFirebaseServicesVersion"
}
```